# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Dynamic page layouts with widget zones

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building an ASP.NET MVC 4 dashboard site.I am trying to come up with a design for my requirement. The site is going to be a three colum layout. Left most column a vertical navigation menu. The centre and right columns will contain the widgets. The same wiget can appear either in centre zone or right zone. Also the requirement is to change the 3 column layout to a 2 column or some other layout with minimal interference in the future.  Its basically a widget system where many different widgets will be displayed to user based on roles and these widgets can be placed in any position/zone. Any suggestions on how to start would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of this requires doing anything special in ASP.Net MVC, it is more about getting the right layout in HTML & CSS .  I would suggest you work on getting a template for the HTML and css working first.  There are plenty of places on the web to find some three column templates to help get you started.

Once you have your HTML & CSS sorted, you will find that ASP.Net MVC is flexible enough to work with whatever layout you come up with.  You will probably find that "Child Actions" will be the best way to handle your widgets.

Comment: Thank you very much. But i would like to have the ability to chose the  layout at runtime and when i say layout i mean to have the header and footer static and the layout of partial views within the header and footer will change based on roles.

Comment: Even with this requirement, your focus should still be on getting the HTML and CSS right.  Changing the layout at runtime could be as simple as changing the CSS either with JQuery, or maybe having the "_layout.cshtml" file returning a slightly different layout based on the users role.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very nice tutorial on how to mimic the layout you want in HTML & CSS

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/inettuts/